# Jquery Change Doesn't work on checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

It just doesn't do anthing

http://jsfiddle.net/pQFy5/1/

Javascript:

```
$("option #toggle-clock").on("change", function() {
    $("#clock").fadeToggle(150);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div><input id="toggle-clock" type="checkbox" checked/><label for="toggle-clock">Relógio</label></div>
<div id="clock">08:00</div>
```

---

Got it, thank's! =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vonDy2791/pQFy5/2/)**

```
$("input#toggle-clock").on("change", function() {
    $("#clock").fadeToggle(150);
});
```

Comment: You can simplify this further into `$("#toggle-clock").change(function()...`

Comment: Yap i know, i just show to Kevin that option is not right to use to call the element but input and remove the space.

Answer (score 0):

There is no element inside of an `option`, it's just

```
$('#toggle-clock');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uvqdG/)

Answer (score 0):

1. It's not an `<option>` element. It's an `<input>`
2. When you have an ID attribute on an element you don't need anything else to identify it since that is alway unique

Change

```
$("option #toggle-clock").on("change", function() {
```

to

```
$("#toggle-clock").on("change", function() {
```